# Console bugging and bugged, evidently

Tags: macos

It appears that a false file path has been installed on a home computer many of us use, that reroutes my emails from gmail, to an Entourage mail app that I do not use, and from my dock have no access to….

My question is, is this even possible, and how would I disable the rifling through my private communications?  I've also found a doc that seems to direct through console adding pictures to my outgoing emails …What, if any, course of action can I take to disable this false file path, and take control of what's being mailed to me, without it being read by others, and what is possibly being sent out with any email I send?

What's also interesting is this all seems to lead back to the iMovie program, which has a series of hidden folders, containing files which are greyed out so I cannot open them.  Yet many of them are names of files of my own, which despite the permissions appearing attributed to me to read and write, I cannot open under my own dock.  Any ideas or suggestions?  It's as though any file I create gets put there, prob through a console directive but then I have no access to it, regardless of what the permissions say?
I am on a Mac Powerbook, OS 10.8.5

Thanks in advance

Here is slice of Console systemdiag:

```
4/20/16 7:41:45.370 PM WindowServer[1172]: Created shield window 0x4 for display 0x04273780
4/20/16 7:41:45.370 PM WindowServer[1172]: Created shield window 0x5 for display 0x003f003d
4/20/16 7:41:45.426 PM WindowServer[1172]: Display 0x04273780: MappedDisplay Unit 0: Mode 1600 x 900, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, IOMode 0x80001008, IODepth 0x1, IOReturn 0x0
4/20/16 7:41:45.429 PM WindowServer[1172]: Display 0x04273780: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1600 x 900], 27 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model 9cde, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0x0000061000009cde0000000004273780
4/20/16 7:41:45.429 PM WindowServer[1172]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2624, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003d
4/20/16 7:41:45.429 PM WindowServer[1172]: CGXPerformInitialDisplayConfiguration
4/20/16 7:41:45.429 PM WindowServer[1172]:   Display 0x04273780: MappedDisplay Unit 0; Vendor 0x610 Model 0x9cde S/N 0 Dimensions 18.70 x 10.51; online enabled built-in, Bounds (0,0)[1600 x 900], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
4/20/16 7:41:45.429 PM WindowServer[1172]:   Display 0x003f003d: MappedDisplay Unit 1; Vendor 0xffffffff Model 0xffffffff S/N -1 Dimensions 0.00 x 0.00; offline enabled, Bounds (2624,0)[1 x 1], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
4/20/16 7:41:45.433 PM WindowServer[1172]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01021a08, GL mask 0x00000003, accelerator 0x00003b93, unit 0, caps QEX|QGL|MIPMAP, vram 256 MB
4/20/16 7:41:45.433 PM WindowServer[1172]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01021a08, GL mask 0x00000003, texture units 8, texture max 8192, viewport max {8192, 8192}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
4/20/16 7:41:45.436 PM loginwindow[1171]: **DMPROXY** Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
4/20/16 7:41:45.503 PM WindowServer[1172]: Created shield window 0x6 for display 0x04273780
4/20/16 7:41:45.503 PM WindowServer[1172]: Display 0x04273780: MappedDisplay Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "iMac"}; TransferTable (256, 3)
4/20/16 7:41:45.557 PM launchctl[1174]: com.apple.findmymacmessenger: Already loaded
4/20/16 7:41:45.559 PM launchctl[1174]: com.apple.store_helper: Already loaded
4/20/16 7:41:45.559 PM launchctl[1174]: com.apple.storeagent: Already loaded
4/20/16 7:41:45.894 PM apsd[475]: Warning: accessing obsolete X509Anchors.
4/20/16 7:41:46.404 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Session 100082 created
4/20/16 7:41:47.397 PM apsd[475]: Warning: accessing obsolete X509Anchors.
4/20/16 7:41:47.427 PM WindowServer[1172]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
4/20/16 7:41:47.502 PM WindowServer[1172]: Display 0x04273780: MappedDisplay Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "iMac"}; TransferTable (256, 3)
4/20/16 7:41:47.517 PM WindowServer[1172]: Display 0x04273780: MappedDisplay Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "iMac"}; TransferTable (256, 3)
4/20/16 7:41:47.869 PM loginwindow[1171]: Login Window Started Security Agent
4/20/16 7:41:47.991 PM locationd[1184]: NOTICE,Location icon should now be in state 0
4/20/16 7:41:48.118 PM UserEventAgent[1176]: cannot find useragent 1102
4/20/16 7:41:48.161 PM SecurityAgent[1183]: MacBuddy was run = 0
4/20/16 7:41:50.254 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder[1151]) Exit timeout elapsed (20 seconds). Killing
4/20/16 7:41:50.910 PM DictationIM[1190]: 3891612: (connect_and_check) Untrusted apps are not allowed to connect to or launch Window Server before login.
4/20/16 7:41:50.911 PM DictationIM[1190]: Window Server is not available.
4/20/16 7:41:50.911 PM DictationIM[1190]: Window Server is not available.
4/20/16 7:41:50.911 PM DictationIM[1190]: Window Server is not available.
4/20/16 7:41:50.911 PM DictationIM[1190]: Window Server is not available.
*4/20/16 7:41:59.973 PM SecurityAgent[1183]: User info context values set for lucy*
4/20/16 7:42:00.224 PM SecurityAgent[1183]: Login Window login proceeding
4/20/16 7:42:00.543 PM loginwindow[1171]: Login Window - Returned from Security Agent
4/20/16 7:42:00.554 PM DictationIM[1190]: Window Server is not available.
4/20/16 7:42:00.554 PM DictationIM[1190]: Window Server is not available.
```

Some strange occurrences that catch my eye:  Windowserver created shield window.
references to GL (my initials in reverse) "mask."
And then Security Agent : User info context values set for lucy*

Comment: I am not the sharpest motherboard in any computing group, but am here to learn, and hopefully, get some help….     Also, looking forward to being more loquacious and social when I get my 20 in rep, so I can talk to all of you in chat.  Until then, goodnight.

Comment: looks like there is someone or something  setting up (or at least trying to set up) a CoreGraphicContext before ther is actually a User logged in onto your Mac. - do you have a external Monitor attached or maybe a Screensharing tool to use your iPad as a external Monitor?

Comment: the comp in question is being used by four different people, two whom have iPads……one of whom I am quite sure remotely controls, perhaps even screenshares or even keylogs what I'm doing, writing, communicating, etc.  When I opened that iMovie app, it was interesting to find any exchanges on conspiracy boards I belong to, copied there, certain emails….essentially all my documents, even including the Notes app, where I keep track of psswrds and reserach links for building threads….  It was all MY stuff, and I never even opened that program before tonight……  Thanks for your comment and help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're being a bit overly-paranoid here, looking for some grand hacking conspiracy where the explanation seems pretty simple to me.

You said in your comments that you keep your passwords in the Notes app on a computer that 4 other people use.

Might it be possible that one of them got a bit curious and just took a peek at your stuff??

Or maybe all 4 of you are also using a shared profile?  If that's the case then maybe nobody got curious and the cross-contamination was purely a function of various apps doing their normal thing.

Let's take Entourage for example:
Someone probably mapped your Gmail account into Entourage to have a look at your email -- having gotten your password from that Notes document you keep. Or maybe you did it yourself by accident when setting up your email account, not realizing that it was Entourage that was prompting you for your account info.  Or maybe you had Gmail set up in Apple's Mail app and Entourage automatically imported it when someone else used it for their email account.  There are lots of ways this could have happened.

As for iMovie:
Programs like iMovie, Photos, iTunes, etc. automatically scan your whole hard drive for their respective content that they can work with.  The default behavior for those apps is to import that info into their own libraries to make themselves easy to use.  If someone else uses iMovie on this computer, that could easily explain why there are files that contain your data in there.  I bet if you checked the Photos app or iTunes, you might find your pictures and music in there too.

Additionally, it is perfectly normal for there to be files you can't open.  In fact, the majority of the files on your computer are not human-readable.

Also, 'GL' -- as in OpenGL -- is a library that Macs use to render graphics on the screen.  The fact that it's your initials backwards is total coincidence.

---

Never, ever, under any circumstances should you have any expectation of privacy on a computer that multiple people use.  You should just assume that anything you do with it can be seen by others.  And do not assume that, because someone else saw what you did, that they were being bad actors.

The only difference between paranoia and curiosity is fear, and the only difference between fear and respect is knowledge.  Arm yourself with knowledge about technology and the ways in which it can both harm you and benefit you.  Educate yourself about your computer, the apps you use, and how they work.  Sites like this will help you.  Turn your curiosity into something constructive and don't let it saddle you with irrational fear (and really, in this case it is irrational).

One last thing; and I say this with the utmost respect and sincerity.... You really should stay away the conspiracy forums.  They're full of half-truths and misunderstanding, and there is rarely anything useful to be gained from them other that a bit of entertainment.

Comment: Obviously, I'm new here.  So, I've tried to familiarize myself with the etiquette, policies, what's encouraged and discouraged, etc.  I'm pretty sure this is not to be regarded so much as a discussion site, in terms of a lot of back and forth, but more the pursuit of knowlege and learning.  So, for a few days, I let this last answer kind of sit here, absorbing it and wondering if I should just keep my mouth shut, or fingers still from the keyboard, as it were.